# How can I use WebGL extensions from web_sys in Rust

Tags: rust, webgl, webassembly, webgl-extensions

I'd like to use [WebGL Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Using_Extensions) from within Rust code that is compiled to WebAssembly. The `web_sys::WebGlRenderingContext` has a method [`get_extension`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.WebGlRenderingContext.html#method.get_extension) which returns a `JsValue`.

I expect there is a way to either use the `dyn_into` method to get an `ANGLE_instanced_arrays` interface, which according to [this webidl](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/blob/master/crates/web-sys/webidls/enabled/WebGLRenderingContext.webidl) may be included in  `web_sys` somewhere, but I can't seem to get at it. If it's not possible to get to the `ANGLE_instanced_arrays` interface, is it possible to call known methods and properties using the `JsValue` directly?

Comment: I could not add the web-sys tag for lack of reputation. If someone wants to add that, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this issue: [wasm-bindgen issue 893 - Figure out how to support interfaces with `NoInterfaceObject` attribute](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/893) The WebGL extensions should be available in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you also posted your question on the wasm-bindgen issues log where they provided some useful information.  For other people who come across this I thought I would share the link.

https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/1257